# What is the best way to point domain to a S3 bucket that doesnt have the domain as bucket name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm new to AWS and all of it's services and my first go at it I started my project with a S3 bucket that was created by default by AWS Vue CLI. I've got Cognito pool & gateway API connected to this bucket but now that I want to connect this project to a custom domain I just purchased I realize the bucket name needs to match the root domain name. From what I understand this will mean that I need to pull all non-aws files from my Vue project, duplicate it, and either reconfigure pre-existing connections or start all over.

I've got my custom domain set up with an empty S3 bucket, Cloudfront, and Router 53 so that's up and working but now I am not sure how to go about transferring this project from buckets.

So basically I started my project with Bucket1 and finished everything that included Cognito Pool & Gateway API. Now I have a custom domain I want to use have Cloudfront and Route 53 with CustomDomain bucket name and I want to have the project from Bucket1 load for the new bucket.

Comment: to clarify: you use the s3 bucket to host static web assets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using Cloud-front you can mitigate this issue.**

Route 53(DNS Name)  --> Cloudfront Url --> S3 origin

As you already created a bucket for website hosting, below steps can help you.

1. Use the [Amazon S3 console](https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/) t to login and search for CloudFront.
2. Click on Create distribution

[image]

3. Create a Web distribution

[image]

4. Select existing bucket in Origin Domain Name and complete the setup.

[image]

5. Update the DNS records for your domain to point your website's CNAME to your CloudFront distribution's domain name. You can find your distribution's domain name in the CloudFront console in a format that is similar to d1234abcd.cloudfront.net.
6. Wait for your DNS changes to propagate and for the previous DNS entries to expire.

Answer (score 2):

The typical AWS way to do this is to use cloudfront - the domain points to cloudfront and cloudfront can point to any bucket name or other source location; when you introduce cloudfront into the mix, the bucketname no longer needs to match the domain name.